# RMI Spring on Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, rmi, spring-remoting

I have a RMI Server application and a RMI Client Application. Both configured with Spring Remoting. Running the client as Java Application runs fine, connecting to the server.

I want to add the RMI Client .jar to a Spring MVCapplication running in Tomcat.
When i deploy the Web Applications i get the following:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orderService' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Users/blitzkr1eg/.m2/repository/adrian/comenziadapter/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/comenziadapter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/springRMI.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException: Lookup of RMI stub failed; nested exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:567)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:384)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:283)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Embedded.start(Embedded.java:825)
at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.startContainer(AbstractRunMojo.java:558)
at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractRunMojo.execute(AbstractRunMojo.java:255)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:107)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:319)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:534)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
Caused by: org.springframework.remoting.RemoteLookupFailureException: Lookup of RMI stub failed; nested exception is java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.lookupStub(RmiClientInterceptor.java:215)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.prepare(RmiClientInterceptor.java:147)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.afterPropertiesSet(RmiClientInterceptor.java:135)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(RmiProxyFactoryBean.java:68)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
... 42 more
Caused by: java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Naming.java:84)
at org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiClientInterceptor.lookupStub(RmiClientInterceptor.java:200)
... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiInvocationWrapper_Stub (no security manager: RMI class loader disabled)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:375)
at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(LoaderHandler.java:165)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:620)
at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(RMIClassLoader.java:247)
at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(MarshalInputStream.java:197)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1574)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1495)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1731)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1328)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:350)
```

In the RMI Server i have

```
<bean class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiServiceExporter">
<!-- does not necessarily have to be the same name as the bean to be exported -->
<property name="serviceName" value="orderService"/>
<property name="service" ref="orderService"/>
<property name="serviceInterface" value="domain.OfertaService"/>
<!-- defaults to 1099 -->
<property name="registryPort" value="1199"/>
```

In the RMI Client i have springRMI.xml:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>
<bean id="orderService" class="org.springframework.remoting.rmi.RmiProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceUrl" value="rmi://localhost:1199/orderService"/>
    <property name="serviceInterface" value="domain.OfertaService"/>
</bean>
```

and

```
public class OrderGatewayRMI implements OrderGateway {

private OfertaService orders;
@Required
public void setOrders(OfertaService orders) {
    this.orders = orders;
}
```

In the web-app i add the RMI client jar dependency
and configure the spring context:

```
<import resource="classpath*:springRMI.xml"/>


<bean id="orderGateway" class="adrian.comenziadapter.OrderGatewayRMI">
</bean>
```

Comment: which spring version on server and client?

Comment: Spring Remoting 2.0.8 on both

Comment: if it is on spring 3, it looks like this bug  https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SPR-6208

Comment: Did anyone found the exact solution? I have the same problem and I tried option to "Start rmiregistry" from the tomcat/lib. But its not working.